# What is causing a npm install nuxt error?

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js, node-gyp

I have just started a Nuxt project on WSL running Ubuntu 20.04.

I am using Node.js LTS/Fermium and I installed some dependencies for the project, but when I try to install Nuxt itself it retrieves some errors and I cannot find the cause:

So, when I do `npm install nuxt` the following errors show up:

```
Debugger attached.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/tino/frontend/hanja/node_modules/deasync
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./build.js
npm ERR! Debugger attached.
npm ERR! Debugger attached.
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.3.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.5 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! (node:5914) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/tino/frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/tino/frontend/hanja/node_modules/deasync/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/tino/frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/tino/.cache/node-gyp/16.3.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/tino/.cache/node-gyp/16.3.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/tino/frontend/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/tino/.cache/node-gyp/16.3.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/tino/frontend/hanja/node_modules/deasync',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Debugger attached.
npm ERR! Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'node -p "require('node-addon-api').include"' returned exit status 0 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/tino/frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/home/tino/.nvm/versions/node/v16.3.0/bin/node" "/home/tino/frontend/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/tino/frontend/hanja/node_modules/deasync
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
npm ERR! Build failed
npm ERR! Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tino/.npm/_logs/2021-06-22T15_14_10_385Z-debug.log
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

I have just started learning Nuxt but I cannot figure out what it causing the error.

Comment: And what does `home/tino/.npm/_logs/2021-06-22T15_14_10_385Z-debug.log` tell you? If the concise log doesn't have enough information, first have a look at the actual log to see if that offers you any clues. (So, don't blindly copy and paste that file into your post: go through it yourself first to see if it tells you what's wrong). Also, what happens if you _don't_ install nuxt (make sure it's not in your package.json etc), and just run `npm install`? Because the concise log starts with a number of lines that suggest you really need to update a few of your dependencies first.

Comment: The log shows exactly the errors that I copy-pasted above. And you are right, I removed it from package.json, ran ```npm install``` and the same errors show up. Any clue where it can come from? It is my first WSL project, so maybe my setup isn't right.

Comment: start removing dependencies from package.json and rerunning `npm install`. At some point, this error will disappear, and the last package you removed is your problem. Although I'm not sure why you'd not just run this in plain windows, Node works just fine, as does pretty much every package you might install. You might need to install VC++ in case anything needs to be compiled from source, but almost everything has prebuilt binaries these days for anything specific-platform-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realized that I had to install the build-essential package in Ubuntu and that was triggering the error:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

After that I was able to install Nuxt and everything is running fine so far!

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove yarn.lock and reinstall again using yarn install.